# Is there such a thing as "zero-sum" variables in c#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to create a structure in c# in which you have paired values, where if one value is set the other value is automatically set oppositely. For example, if I had a pairing like:

```
{
  public bool Courageous;
  public bool Cowardly;
}
```

So if one of the two gets set, the other gets "unset". Is there such a thing as related zero-sum variables?

Comment: You can define your own setters and getters for those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try properties

```
{
    private bool _courageous;
    public bool Courageous 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _courageous;
        }
        set
        {
            _courageous = value;
            _cowardly = !value;
        }
    }

    private bool _cowardly;
    public bool Cowardly 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _cowardly;
        }
        set
        {
            _cowardly = value;
            _courageous = !value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or as [zzzzbov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497418/zzzzbov) and [Amy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47589/amy) suggests, with one backing field

```
{
    private bool _courageous;
    public bool Courageous 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _courageous;
        }
        set
        {
            _courageous = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Cowardly 
    {
        get 
        {
            return !_courageous;
        }
        set
        {
            _courageous = !value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or with no backing field, [see other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581213/3708462)

```
{
    public bool Courageous{ get; set; }
    public bool Cowardly { get { return !Courageous; } set { Courageous = !value; } }
}
```

Comment: They can share the same backing field.  There's no need for two fields.

Comment: You guys are great. I like it. I think it would be a super idea to have a construct in C# that is easier to declare than going through properties. Still, I like it! -su

Comment: @Amy That's right, they can share same backing field. But it is a good design practice to keep separate field for every properties, which may help in future.

Comment: @EmdadulSawon, no it's really not. It's better to write things as simply as possible with no extra fluff. If requirements change in the future, you can add the necessary extra backing field then. See also [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Aw, @Emdadul Sawon - I thought I'd accepted, but I had hit the up-vote! I had to click the checkmark to accept. Thanks!  -sulu

Comment: @zzzzBov But the Open/closed principle in design pattern say other. You should not modify your code, you should just add new things.

Comment: @EmdadulSawon private fields don't impact OCP in any way. The whole point of OCP is that you can change the private fields all you want as you go and it shouldn't impact anything, as your public interface will remain the same.

Comment: Having two separate fields creates the possibility that the object can be in an invalid state.  Both fields can be true, and both can be false.  That violates the contract that the properties should always be unequal.  This is not possible if you use a single backing field.

Answer (score 5):

Do not expose the properties directly, instead use property accessors to mutate private fields as required:

```
{
    private bool _courageous;
    private bool _cowardly;

    public bool Courageous
    {
        get { return _courageous; }
        set
        {
            _courageous = value;
            _cowardly = !value;
        }
    }

    public bool Cowardly
    {
        get { return _cowardly; }
        set
        {
            _cowardly = value;
            _courageous = !value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, more simply in this case since you have only two `bool`s which are always the logical inverse of the other:

```
{
    public bool Courageous{ get; set; }
    public bool Cowardly { get { return !Courageous; } set { Courageous = !value; } }
}
```

Your specific case will determine whether you can use a common backing field and perform the mutation in the publicly exposed property of one (or other) property, or would instead need to have separate backing fields and more complex accessors.

But the general point is that properties and property accessors can be used to fabricate pretty much any such behaviour you need.

Comment: Make `Courageous` a property in your second example. That is `public bool Courageous {get; set;}`